# kill unsigned / signed comparison error

Tags: c++, comparison, g++, suppress-warnings

In general, I want warnings of unsigned vs signed.

However, in this particular case, I want it suppressed;

```
std::vector<Blah> blahs;

for(int i = 0; i < blahs.size(); ++i) { ...
```

I want to kill this comparison.

Thanks!

(using g++)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should fix, not suppress. Use an unsigned type:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < blahs.size(); ++i)
```

You can also use `unsigned`, but `size_t` is more appropriate here (and may have a different, larger, range). If you're only using `i` to iterate and don't need its value in the loop, use iterators instead:

```
for (auto iter = blahs.begin(), end = blahs.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
```

If your compiler does not support `auto`, replace `auto` with `T::iterator` or `T::const_iterator`, where `T` is the type of `blahs`. If your compiler supports a fuller subset of C++11, though, do this:

```
for (auto& element : blahs)
```

Which is best of all.

---

Strictly speaking, the above is not "correct". It should be:

```
typedef std::vector<Blah> blah_vec;
blah_vec blahs;

for (blah_vec::size_type i = 0; i < blahs.size(); ++i)
```

But this can be verbose, and every implementation I know uses `size_t` as `size_type` anyway.

---

If for some reason you really need a signed integer type for `i`, you'll have to cast:

```
// assumes size() will fit in an int
for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(blahs.size()); ++i)

// assumes i will not be negative (so use an unsigned type!)
for (int i = 0; static_cast<size_t>(i) < blahs.size(); ++i)

// and the technically correct way, assuming i will not be negative
for (int i = 0; static_cast<blah_vec::size_type>(i) < blahs.size(); ++i)
```